# Compress Multiple Files\Folders and encrypt zip with password via Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, zip, 7zip

I'm Trying to make a quick script in powershell
that will compress multiple folder
(or files doesnt matter for now, in my example its folders)
and add to each zip file a random password
and export the passwords for each zip file, to csv.

This is what i got so far...

```
$path = "\\path\of\folders"
$source = Get-ChildItem -Path \\path\of\folders -Filter "*?" -Directory

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

Foreach ($s in $source){
    $destination = Join-path -path $path -ChildPath "$($s.name).zip"

    If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}

    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $destination)
}
```

with this i'm able to compress each folder in the main folder, to zip files each with its name.

where i get complicated to manage, is how to add a random password for each of the zip files... and after that i'll just add | Export-Csv -Path \to\my\path\passwords.csv (unless im wrong about that export)

any ideas on that?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe 7zip would be better solution for this than the `io.compression`.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to create a zip file with password using .Net. You may look at [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) for that. The [commandline version](https://7ziphelp.com/7zip-command-line) of that has a parameter `-p` to compress with password.

Comment: ok yeah i've managed that now, but im still strangling with generating random passwords.... is there a way? trying to created random generated password for each of them and then export it to csv file

Comment: alright, looks like i managed it.
still some issue with exporting all to csv file, but i got some workaround for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to work out a script that compressing and encrypting the zip files.

```
 if (-not (Test-Path "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe")){
    Write-Warning "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$7z = ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe")

foreach($subfolder in (Get-ChildItem "\\path_of_directoris" -Directory))
{
    $pass =  [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,2) 
    $Source    = $subfolder.fullname 
    $Target    = "\\path_of_directoris\$($subfolder.name).zip"
    & $7z "a" "-mx=9" "$Target" "$Source" "-p$pass" | Export-CSV -Path "\\path_to_store_pass\passwords.csv"
    echo $subfolder, $pass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to treat the archiving and encryption as separate operations. 7z/winzip/et.al. has had issues with encryption in the past, and other vulnerabilities. It's good at compression and archiving though!

I have recently released a command line toolbox for file encryption, based on the tried and proven cryptography code of AxCrypt that could work well here. It's also portable between Windows, macOS and Linux, and is interoperable with AxCrypt for desktop app decryption which can sometimes be useful.

Check it out at https://github.com/xecrets/xecrets-file-cli, it's licensed under GNU GPL v3.